# How to update only part of the JSON?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Customer ID (Primary Key)|Gamestats (JSON entry) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

JSON:

```
{
  "Gamestats": [
    {
      "ID": "QuickShootingMode",
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "ID": "FastReloadMode",  // Just want to update this and not update the entire JSON
      "status": 0
    }
  ],
  "CustomerID": "xyz"
}
```

I want to update only parts of the JSON. What is the best way to do it? Eg, update the `QuickShootingMode` to be false.

One way is to make a call and fetch the JSON and then Iterate the JSON and update the value and then put the new JSON back in dynamo DB. It means it would make 2 calls
A) to get the data and
B) to put the data in DB.

Is there a better way by which I could directly update the data and avoid making these extra network calls? I could convert each key of the JSON to be a column in dynamo BD, but if the number of keys grows then I’ll end up having lots of column (which might be a bad design), hence I think having the JSON saved in one column `Game stats` would make more sense.

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap<>();   
    AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = dynamoDBClient.getDynamoDB();
    key.put(USER_ID_KEY, new AttributeValue().withS("xyz"));
    key.put("Gamedata", new AttributeValue().withS("some JSON"));
    PutItemRequest request = new PutItemRequest()
            .withTableName(table)
            .withItem(key);

 PutItemResult result = dynamoDB.putItem(request);
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Use the update api.

Comment: Would that update the part of the JSON? @cementblocks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like from your question you are storing stringified JSON. If so an `update` won't help you, but as far as I can tell there is no value in storing stringified JSON instead of using dynamodb maps and lists.

You can use an [update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingNestedMapAttributes) to set a nested attribute in a map or a list. Using a map instead of a list for the gamestats attribute is better because then you don't have to worry about the order of the attributes.

Javascript example with Gamestats being a map.

```js
dynamodb.update({
  TableName: table,
  Key: key,
  UpdateExpression: 'SET #gs.#qs.#status = :newStatus',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {'#gs': 'Gamestats', '#qs': 'QuickShootingMode', '#status': 'status' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':newStatus': false }
}, callback)
```